# looking for some advise on setting up a sports event livestream with local playback

Tags: streaming, live-recording

I have recently been tasked with setting up a live stream for a Karate Tournament.  Never did anything like it before but I'm the organization's technical wiz so its landed on my lap.

I'm looking for some advise on where to start equipment wise.  I have a cropped sensor Nikon d3400 with a 35mm lens.  So looking on advise on whether to use that or to look at a goPro or similar camera.

My other requirement is to have a laptop available that if the referee would like to see a replay of recent footage to determine if there is a foul we can do this without interrupting the live stream.

So really I am looking for advise on the following.

- Should I stick with the entry dslr or investing in a sports camera?
- Will there be any issues with streaming and also recording for instant playback from the same camera.

I have almost a year to get this setup working so really just looking for a bit of advise so i can get started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there will be problems trying to stream the live-image from a dslr. Usually, you would use a multicam-setup for a livestream such as this, including scenes for intermissions, transitions, etc.

Normally, you would use a mixer like the ones from black-magic, [here's](https://www.videodata.de/shop/products/de/Studiotechnik/Videomischer/Blackmagic-ATEM-Television-Studio-HD.html?refID=GOOGLE_RSS_FEED_REFID&gclid=Cj0KCQiAn4PkBRCDARIsAGHmH3epXnlnktBKWuCk1WJBo73YUxb-_sWw1Z4hkQpaW0l5LqEFdlODhCMaAkDWEALw_wcB) a link to it. Using it, you would want to feed an sdi signal from the camera into the mixer and send the image from the mixer to a distributer (like a pc or laptop) which will then be able to stream the image.

Unfortunately, you can't just plug a gopro into your pc and press "stream image".